# How to get Function expression Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

[image]

I'm using Apache POI Library, how can I read the function expression from the excel.
I need to read both the value **15** and the expression which has been used to calculate it, **=5+10**. Does Apache POI Support this functionality?

Comment: Have you tried (anything like) to treat that expression as a formula and check the result of `cell.getCellFormula()`? For a numeric value receive the result of `cell.getNumericCellValue()`.

Comment: cell.getCellFormula is getting formula like SUM(A1+A3).

Comment: `cell.getCellFormula()` will get a `String` containing "5+10" for your cell `B2`.

Comment: The Type of B2 is being taken as a Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC. It's getting 15 directly. If I try to get formula from Numeric cell, its throwing an exception.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a formula value from a numeric formula cell

Comment: Cannot reproducing. For me a cell containing `=5+10` is a formula cell and `apache poi` will get it as a such.

Comment: Can you post your Running Code as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using  current `apache poi 4.1.2` the following code prints all cell contents dependent on the `CellType` of the cells. For formula cells the formula gets printed as well as the cached formula result.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;

class ReadExcelFormulas {

 static void printCellContent(Cell cell, CellType type) {
  switch (type) {
   case STRING:
    System.out.println("String: " + cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
    break;
   case NUMERIC:
    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
     System.out.println("Date: " + cell.getDateCellValue());
    } else {
     System.out.println("Number: " + cell.getNumericCellValue());
    }
    break;
   case BOOLEAN:
    System.out.println("Boolean: " + cell.getBooleanCellValue());
    break;
   case FORMULA:
    System.out.print("Formula: " + cell.getCellFormula());
    System.out.print(", Formula result is ");
    printCellContent(cell, cell.getCachedFormulaResultType());
    break;
   case BLANK:
    System.out.println("Blank cell.");
    break;
   default:
    System.out.println("This should not occur.");
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Excel.xlsx"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
    System.out.print(cellRef.formatAsString());
    System.out.print(" - ");
    printCellContent(cell, cell.getCellType());
   }
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Having the `Excel.xlsx` the same as in your screen shot, the result will be:

```
A1 - Number: 1.0
B1 - Number: 2.0
C1 - Formula: SUM(A1:B1), Formula result is Number: 3.0
A2 - Number: 6.0
B2 - Formula: 5+10, Formula result is Number: 15.0
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue was with the version of Apache POI which I have been using. I upgraded to the latest version 4.1.2, it's working fine now.